# Updating app from iOS 5.1 to 6.0 - new warnings?

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

I'm new to the update/versioning process of an app and Xcode, so here are a few questions:

I create the app and was approved by apple running in the old xcode and simulator 5.1. I DIDN'T have any warning messages. Now when running in new xcode and simulator 6.0, I get 20+ new warning messages.

Does Apple expect NO warnings in any build in any version?
Do I need to fix all of the warnings or only certain ones? 
(i.e. my app files VS external 3rd party frameworks/libraries that I included/imported into the app) 
Fixing them for this version 6.0 may break for older version, correct?
The app was create with a target of 5.1, but wanted to move that back to 4.3 (more user coverage), I can only test that on the simulator is that okay?

Here are some example warnings:
- JSONKit.m - Semantic Issue - Direct Access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
- Many types ones like - Format specifices type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
- Cocoa API Issue - Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 4.3 (more user coverage)?? A few months ago 5.0 was already above 80 % adoption. Has it gone back?

Comment: I wasn't aware the adoption rate was that high. Is it not best to use the lowest target possible, so the most of number of iphone users phones are compatible? Either way, any input on how I should address the warnings? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is that compilers generate errors and warnings.

Errors are fatal problems that prevent the compiler being able to parse the source and generate code.

Compiler warnings are about potential issues which do not prevent the compilation succeeding but may cause issues at run-time, or flag issues you should be aware of.

You should understand the issue that each of the warnings is describing, and decide whether to take action.

Specifically, deprecation warnings are a 'heads-up' that future versions of iOS (or a library, or whatever) may no longer support the API you're using, and it's time to think about moving to the new API, or remove the code that relies on that API.

Often, warnings can be safely ignored, but it's best practice to keep your code clean of warnings so any new warnings are apparent, and grab your attention.

Apple will not reject an app based on compilation warnings.  Apple only see the submitted binary, and don't have access to the source code and any associated warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has no idea what warnings you got compiling your code. All they see is a signed binary, one that either works (approve) or doesn't (reject).

Why are you getting them now? Because the new version of Xcode has better heuristics for checking suspicious code. Deprecation warnings are because you're now using a newer version of iOS as a target.

Should you fix them? Probably. I do release code with compile warnings but you need to consider the risks of not fixing the warning on a case-by-case basis. Some are more important or dangerous than others.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of using JSONKit I would recommend wrapping your code around an adapater class so you can use NSJSONSerialization for versions above or equal to 5.0.

How large is the user base with iOS version lower than 5.0? I read that its less than 1 percent?